# Set WPF Binding Source to DataGrid Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` with 18 columns and each column has a `TextBox` above it so I can filter the column.

Each `TextBox` binds `Width` to `ActualWidth` of the column.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Column1}"
             Text="{Binding FilterFirstName}"/>
    <TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Column2}"
             Text="{Binding FilterLastName}"/>
    <TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Column3}"
             Text="{Binding FilterAge}"/>
    <!-- 15 more -->
</StackPanel>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridUsers" Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1" Width="*"
            Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Width="*"
            Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Width="*"
            Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        <!-- 15 more -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I know that I can bind `TextBox` `Text` to a `List<string>` like this:

```
<TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Column1}"
         Text="{Binding Filters[0]}"/>
<TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Column2}"
         Text="{Binding Filters[1]}"/>
<TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Column3}"
         Text="{Binding Filters[2]}"/>
```

I would like to bind `Width` of the `TextBox` to `ActualWidth` of the column with something like this:

```
<TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, Source=dataGridUsers.Columns[0]}"
         Text="{Binding Filters[0]}"/>
<TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, Source=dataGridUsers.Columns[1]}"
         Text="{Binding Filters[1]}"/>
<TextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, Source=dataGridUsers.Columns[2]}"
         Text="{Binding Filters[2]}"/>
```

Because then I could use `ItemsControl` instead of `StackPanel` but **it doesn't work this way**.

Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to use `ItemsControl` with `TextBox` to filter DataGrid columns.**

It is possible to use `ItemsControl` and bind to `DataGrid.Columns` like this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Columns,
              ElementName=dataGrid}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth}">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <local:ListIndexToValueConverter
                        x:Key="listIndexToValueConverter"/>
                </TextBox.Resources>
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource
                listIndexToValueConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Filters"
                                 ElementName="userControl"/>
                        <Binding Path="DisplayIndex"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn DisplayIndex="0" Width="*" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn DisplayIndex="1" Width="*" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn DisplayIndex="2" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Because you set the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to `DataGrid.Columns` instead of `DataContext.Filters` you have to set `DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex` and use `IMultiValueConverter` to be able to access `DataContext.Filters` again:

```
public class ListIndexToValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private IList _list;
    private int _index;
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 2)
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        if (values[0] is IList && values[1] is int)
        {
            _list = (IList)values[0];
            _index = (int)values[1];
            return _list[_index];
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _list[_index] = value;
        return new object[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

The `ViewModel`:

```
public class UsersViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    private ICollectionView _usersView;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Filters { get; set; }
    public UsersViewModel()
    {
        _usersView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Users);
        _usersView.Filter = delegate (object item)
        {
            User user = item as User;
            List<string> columns = new List<string>()
                { user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Age };
            bool include = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filters[i]) &&
                    columns[i].IndexOf(Filters[i],
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
                {
                    include = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return include;
        };
        Filters.CollectionChanged += (object sender,
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) => _usersView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant bind to `DataGrid` Columns properties because they are only in the logical tree - not the visual tree. 
The only way to do something like this is to change the `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate` and create a new `DataTemplate` with the filter `TextBox` within.

Comment: yes, just put the TextBox in the column header. But remember then to set proper `DataContext` for the bindings

Comment: I am just curious: why would there be a difference in binding something in visual tree and something in logical tree?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed bind to the Columns of your `DataGrid` by doing so

```
<TextBox Width="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=dataGridUsers}" />
```

But this won't work for what you want to achieve. As soon as you reorder the columns at runtime the order won't match the order of your TextBoxes anymore. So you have to reorder them too.
Note: [`DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindexproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the current index within your `DataGrid`.

---

A much better approach and the recommended way would be placing your "FilterTextBoxes" inside the headers of your columns by changing the `DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate`

Comment: Thank you for the `DisplayIndex` hint, I was able to use it in a `MultiBinding` so that it always works as it should.